# EC2 Internal Sockets

Tags: sockets, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to have two process communicate through a socket connection. One of these is a python app, and the other is a php script.

I've created and tested the client/server combination on my home computer and it functions properly. However, when I deploy onto an EC2 instance (ubuntu 10.10 64bit ami + apache + php) I get an unable to connect to socket error (111 Connection Refused) from the php script. The python app is able to bind to the socket and listen to messages but the php script is unable to send messages.

I've opened the required ports in the amazon security group and I can connect to the port externally using telnet. However if I attempt to connect with telnet from within the server I get the same connection refused error.

How can I solve this issue?

Edit: Both processes are on the same instance

Comment: these two processes are on the same instance or different ones?

Comment: can you ping each other? are they under the same datacenter?

Comment: both processes are on the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with EC2 explicitly. I was not binding to localhost, but instead binding to my hostname. On a local network that was the same as my localhost ip, however on ec2 it was not.  Switching to binding to localhost fixed the issue.